# Lithium test dashboard is not displaying my new test case controller

Tags: lithium

I have added new test controller [buyControllerTest.php] under app\tests\cases\controllers but with some reason I am not able to see it's listing on test dashboard !.

Is it something to do with cache?

log say

```
 Class 'app\tests\cases\controllers\buyControllerTest' not found in /my-path/libraries/lithium/test/Dispatcher.php
```

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try capitalizing your class name and filename to "BuyControllerTest". That is the format Lithium expects.

Also, check your namespace declaration in your file and make sure that matches.

Last, restart your web server. Lithium can cache library paths in APC. If you don't have the APC (or APCu) php extension, then you may delete files in your app/resources/tmp/cache directory to clear the cache.